# Remove the border covering text using phtml code

Tags: cart, phtml

please visit [link](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/zephyr-mechanix-nx0-small.html) & click on "Buy Now" button.

than you can see this image :

[image]

using CTRL + F, search for "**Check Delivery**" text. you can see 2 texts.

text which is present below is fine. but in above

i want to remove the outer box covering these texts.

i can use `border-width : 0px 0px 0px`

but it will hide the box which is present in right-bottom also.  i want to hide only box present inside table.

**Default.phtml** code :

```
app/design/frontend/default/default/template/mpassignproduct/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml

<?php /* Custom Code */?>
    <?php
    $_item = $this->getItem();
    $isVisibleProduct = $_item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility();
    $canApplyMsrp = Mage::helper('catalog')->canApplyMsrp($_item->getProduct(), Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Source_Msrp_Type::TYPE_BEFORE_ORDER_CONFIRM);
    $mpAssignId=0;
    foreach($_item->getOptions() as $option) {
        $temp=unserialize($option['value']);
        if($temp['mpassignproduct_id'])
            $mpAssignId=$temp['mpassignproduct_id'];
    }
    if($mpAssignId) {
        $users = Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mpassignproduct_id',array('eq'=>$mpAssignId));
    } else {
        $users = Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$_item->getProductId()));
    }
    foreach ($users as $value) {
        if($mpAssignId) 
            $sellerid = $value->getSellerId();
        else
            $sellerid = $value->getUserid();
        $sellername1 = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($sellerid)->getName();
    }
    $users = Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageuserid',array('eq'=>$sellerid));
    foreach ($users as $value) {
        $profileurl = $value->getProfileurl();
    }
    ?>
<?php /* Custom Code */?>




<?php
$sellerid = 0;
$profileurl = '';
$_item = $this->getItem();
$isVisibleProduct = $_item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility();
$canApplyMsrp = Mage::helper('catalog')->canApplyMsrp($_item->getProduct(), Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Source_Msrp_Type::TYPE_BEFORE_ORDER_CONFIRM);
$users = Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$_item->getProductId()));
foreach ($users as $value) {
    $sellerid = $value->getUserid();
    $sellername = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($sellerid)->getName();
}

$prod_CodAvailable = Mage::getModel('mpcashondelivery/pricerules')->getCodAvailablility($_item->getQty()*$_item->getWeight(),$sellerid);

$users = Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageuserid',array('eq'=>$sellerid));
foreach ($users as $value) {
    $profileurl = $value->getProfileurl();
}
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()):?><a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" class="product-image"><?php endif;?><img src="<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(75); ?>" width="75" height="75" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>" /><?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()):?></a><?php endif;?></td>
    <td>
        <h2 class="product-name">
        <?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()):?>
            <!-- <a href="<?php //echo $this->getProductUrl() ?>"> -->
                <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>
            <!-- </a> -->
        <?php else: ?>
            <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </h2>
        <div class="soled-by">
        <?php
        if($profileurl){
            ?>
            <?php echo Mage::helper('mpcashondelivery')->__('Seller : ')." "?>
               <!--  <a href="<?php //echo $this->getUrl('marketplace/seller/profile').$profileurl; ?>" target="_blank"><?php //echo $sellername1;?></a> -->
               <strong><?php echo $sellername1;?></strong>
            <?php
        } ?>
    </div>
        <?php
        $prod_coll = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());
        if($prod_coll->getCodAvailable() && $prod_CodAvailable){ ?>
            <div class="Cash-on-delivery-in-shopping-cart">
                <strong><?php echo Mage::helper('mpcashondelivery')->__('CASH ON DELIVERY IS AVAILABLE'); ?></strong>
                <!-- <img src="<?php //echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/quest.png'); ?>" class='questimg' title="<?php //echo Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/mpcashondelivery/description') ?>"/> -->
            </div>
            <?php
        }else{ ?>
            <div class="Cash-on-delivery-not-available-in-shopping-cart">
                <strong><?php echo Mage::helper('mpcashondelivery')->__('CASH ON DELIVERY NOT AVAILABLE'); ?></strong>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        <?php if ($_options = $this->getOptionList()):?>
        <dl class="item-options">
            <?php foreach ($_options as $_option) : ?>
            <?php $_formatedOptionValue = $this->getFormatedOptionValue($_option) ?>
            <dt><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_option['label']) ?></dt>
            <dd<?php if (isset($_formatedOptionValue['full_view'])): ?> class="truncated"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $_formatedOptionValue['value'] ?>
                <?php if (isset($_formatedOptionValue['full_view'])): ?>
                <div class="truncated_full_value">
                    <dl class="item-options">
                        <dt><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_option['label']) ?></dt>
                        <dd><?php echo $_formatedOptionValue['full_view'] ?></dd>
                    </dl>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </dd>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
        <?php endif;?>
        <?php if ($messages = $this->getMessages()): ?>
        <?php foreach ($messages as $message): ?>
            <p class="item-msg <?php echo $message['type'] ?>">* <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($message['text']) ?></p>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php $addInfoBlock = $this->getProductAdditionalInformationBlock(); ?>
        <?php if ($addInfoBlock): ?>
            <?php echo $addInfoBlock->setItem($_item)->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif;?>
    </td>

    <?php //if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllowInCart()) : ?>
    <!-- <td class="a-center">
        <?php //if ($isVisibleProduct): ?>
            <a href="<?php //echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getMoveFromCartUrl($_item->getId()); ?>" class="link-wishlist use-ajax"><?php //echo $this->__('Move'); ?></a>
        <?php //endif ?>
    </td> -->
    <?php //endif ?>

    <?php if ($canApplyMsrp): ?>
        <td class="a-right"<?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?> colspan="2"<?php endif; ?>>
            <span class="cart-price">
                <span class="cart-msrp-unit"><?php echo $this->__('See price before order confirmation.'); ?></span>
                <?php $helpLinkId = 'cart-msrp-help-' . $_item->getId(); ?>
                <a id="<?php echo $helpLinkId ?>" href="#" class="map-help-link"><?php echo $this->__("What's this?"); ?></a>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    Catalog.Map.addHelpLink($('<?php echo $helpLinkId ?>'), "<?php echo $this->__("What's this?") ?>");
                </script>
            </span>
        </td>
    <?php else: ?>

        <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceExclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
        <td class="a-right">
            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                <span class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('eunit-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
            <?php else: ?>
                <span class="cart-price">
            <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxDisposition()); ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()) ?>
                <?php endif; ?>

            </span>

            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item)): ?>

                <div class="cart-tax-info" id="eunit-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>" style="display:none;">
                    <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 1, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                        <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                            <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount'],true,true); ?></span>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                        <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                            <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount'],true,true); ?></span>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 4, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                        <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                            <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount'],true,true); ?></span>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>



                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <div class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('eunit-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
                        <span class="weee"><?php echo Mage::helper('weee')->__('Total'); ?>: <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxDisposition()); ?></span>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
        <?php endif; ?><!-- inclusive price starts here -->
        <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceInclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
        <td>
            <?php $_incl = $this->helper('checkout')->getPriceInclTax($_item); ?>
            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                <span class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('unit-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
            <?php else: ?>
                <span class="cart-price">
            <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl + Mage::helper('weee')->getWeeeTaxInclTax($_item)); ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl-$_item->getWeeeTaxDisposition()) ?>
                <?php endif; ?>

            </span>
            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item)): ?>

                <div class="cart-tax-info" id="unit-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>" style="display:none;">
                    <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 1, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                        <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                            <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                        <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                            <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 4, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                        <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                            <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>

                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <div class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('unit-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
                        <span class="weee"><?php echo Mage::helper('weee')->__('Total incl. tax'); ?>: <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl + Mage::helper('weee')->getWeeeTaxInclTax($_item)); ?></span>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>


    <!-- QTY increase button start -->

    <td class="a-center">

    <!--added my urv -->
        <div class="qty_cart"> 

    <div class="qty-ctl">    
    <button title="Decrease Qty" onclick="changeQty('<?php echo 'qty_'.$_item->getId() ?>',0); return false;" class="decrease"><?php echo $this->__('decrease') ?></button>    
    </div>      
  <!-- end added my urv --> 
    <input id="<?php echo 'qty_'.$_item->getId() ?>" name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" value="<?php echo $this->getQty() ?>" size="4" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" maxlength="12" />
    <!--added my urv -->    
    <div class="qty-ctl">         
    <button title="Increase Qty" onclick="changeQty('<?php echo 'qty_'.$_item->getId() ?>',1); return false;" class="increase"><?php echo $this->__('increase') ?></button>       
    </div>  
<!-- endadded my urv -->    

    </div>  
    </td>


     <!-- QTY increase button end -->

    <!-- zip code -->


    <td>

    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('delivery')->toHtml();  ?> 

    <?php if (($_shippingRateGroups = $this->getEstimateRates())): 

    if(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMyShipMessage()){
    echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMyShipMessage();
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsMyShipMessage();
    }
    endif; ?>

    </td>

    <!-- zip code end -->




    <!--Sub total starts here -->
    <?php if (($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceExclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()) && !$_item->getNoSubtotal()): ?>
    <td class="a-right">
        <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
            <span class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('esubtotal-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
        <?php else: ?>
            <span class="cart-price">
        <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($canApplyMsrp): ?>
                <span class="cart-msrp-subtotal">--</span>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getRowTotal()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedRowAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxRowDisposition()); ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getRowTotal()) ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

        </span>
        <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item)): ?>

            <div class="cart-tax-info" id="esubtotal-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>" style="display:none;">
                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 1, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['row_amount'],true,true); ?></span>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['row_amount'],true,true); ?></span>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 4, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['row_amount'],true,true); ?></span>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>

            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                <div class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('esubtotal-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
                    <span class="weee"><?php echo Mage::helper('weee')->__('Total'); ?>: <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getRowTotal()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedRowAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxRowDisposition()); ?></span>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </td>
    <?php endif; ?>



    <?php if (($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceInclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()) && !$_item->getNoSubtotal()): ?>
    <td>
        <?php $_incl = $this->helper('checkout')->getSubtotalInclTax($_item); ?>
        <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
            <span class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('subtotal-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
        <?php else: ?>
            <span class="cart-price">
        <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($canApplyMsrp): ?>
                <span class="cart-msrp-subtotal">--</span>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl + Mage::helper('weee')->getRowWeeeTaxInclTax($_item)); ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl-$_item->getWeeeTaxRowDisposition()) ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

        </span>


        <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item)): ?>

            <div class="cart-tax-info" id="subtotal-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>" style="display:none;">
                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 1, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['row_amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['row_amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 4, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="weee"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($tax['row_amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>

            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                <div class="cart-tax-total" onclick="taxToggle('subtotal-item-tax-details<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>', this, 'cart-tax-total-expanded');">
                    <span class="weee"><?php echo Mage::helper('weee')->__('Total incl. tax'); ?>: <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl + Mage::helper('weee')->getRowWeeeTaxInclTax($_item)); ?></span>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </td>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <td class="a-center"><a href="<?php echo $this->getDeleteUrl()?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Remove item')?>" class="btn-remove btn-remove2"><?php echo $this->__('Remove item')?></a></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you can set a class or id for delivery container and depending on this use css rule like .abc_test div {border:none !important}.** add class online 257 of your phtml which will look like

```
<td class="abc_test">

<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('delivery')->toHtml();  ?> 

<?php if (($_shippingRateGroups = $this->getEstimateRates())): 

if(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMyShipMessage()){
echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMyShipMessage();
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsMyShipMessage();
}
endif; ?>

</td>
```

and resulting output[image]

Comment: This is classic answer..... Thanks a lot....